# TypeError: $scope.weatherAPI.get is not a function

Tags: angularjs, get, angularjs-scope

```
weatherApp.controller('forecastController', ['$scope', '$http','$resource', '$routeParams', 'cityService','$sce',function($scope, $http,$resource, $routeParams, cityService,$sce) {

    $scope.city = cityService.city;

    $scope.weatherAPI = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather",{ callback: "JSON_CALLBACK" }, { get: { method: "JSONP" }} );
    //$scope.weatherResult=$sce.valueOf($scope.weatherAPI);

    $scope.weatherFinal= $scope.weatherAPI.get ({q: $scope.city,appid:'uniqueid'}); //uniqueid cannot be revealed.
    console.log($scope.weatherFinal);
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to assign to a $scope variable, try the following,

```
$scope.getWeather = function() {
    url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+$scope.city+"&mode=json&APPID="+$scope.appId; 
    $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
    }, function myError(response) {
        onsole.log(response.statusText);
    });
};
```